# Dropdown Opens Under Modal - CSS Issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal which has several dropdowns inside it due to lots of stuff I set `overflow: auto` so that it has scroll bar (see scroll bar at right side of the pic).

Now problem is when I click dropdown it opens under the modal (see image) I need dropdown to open over that modal.

P.S: I googled and found lots of solution where we need to set modal CSS property `overflow: visible`. But in my case I have to set `overflow: auto` coz I have lots of stuff inside modal and scroll bar is necessary otherwise modal height goes over the page.

Need some CSS expert to fix this issue.

**Modal CSS**

```
.modal {
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: auto; 
}
```

**Dropdown CSS**

```
ul.dropdown {
  z-index: 999999;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

 ul.dropdown li {
  top: 110%;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 197px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is a duplicate. Can you post all the relevant code please?

Comment: @ZimSystem I have added more code

Answer (score -2):

Hi you need to give the absolute position for your dropdown ul like this

```
ul.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and for the li childrens :

```
ul.dropdown li {
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 197px;
}
```