# Dropdown Hidden Inside Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap modal with several dropdown into it due to bunch of stuff I set `overflow: auto` CSS property to have a scroll bar in modal.

Problem is when I open any of the dropdown it does not appear out of the modal (due to that CSS property `overflow: auto`) it hides under the modal (see image).

I want to appear that dropdown out of that modal I tried everything `z-index: 999999; position: absolute` etc but does not seems to work.

I googled and all solutions I found was to remove that `overflow: auto` property and to put `overflow:visible` but as I mentioned due to bunch of dropdowns (around 150) I must need to put scroll bar for overflow otherwise modal height mess the page.

**CSS (mandatory)**

```
.modal-body {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

The simple solution is you just replace that `overflow:auto` to `visible` and it works, but I need solution with keeping `overflow:auto`;

here is the working example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ukh4nq3/)

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Didn't you already ask this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930012/dropdown-opens-under-modal-css-issue

Comment: Yeah but this time I came up with more details also an example on JSFiddle

Comment: Ok, but you should edit/improve the existing question instead

Comment: Big Brother is watching you! @ZimSystem

Comment: Yes, I like your comments. Because its just fun that you encountered both his question twice on 1 day. haha

Comment: but he didn't answer

Comment: Yeah well, if someone reads the question, it doesn't mean he knows the awnser ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved after upgrading bootstrap from `3.x` to `4.x`, now bootstrap 4 is taking care of all these edge cases out of the box.

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/28513 (still happens with v5.2.2)

Comment: it still doesn't work, when we add overflow:auto to modal-body

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, however not without breaking bootstraps *responsiveness*.

reset the `position: relative;` back to its *initial* `position: static;`

```
.modal-body,
.modal-body .dropdown {
   position: static;
}
```

The problem with it is that the dropdown doesn't know at which *position* it should be. So you have to *position it yourself*

```
.modal-body .dropdown-menu {
  top: 100px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

I woudn't recommend this solution, but just stick to the way bootstrap handles elements.

```css
.modal-body {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-body,
.modal-body .dropdown {
  position: static !important;
}

.modal-body .dropdown-menu {
  top: 100px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="#">
            Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
        <br>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
            <li>four</li>
            <li>five</li>
            <li>six</li>
            <li>seven</li>
            <li>eight</li>
          </ul>
          
           
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Done</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```